# How to install only one executable with make install?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a project with CMakeLists.txt and 7 executables with it:

```
/Project
  /build
  /Subprogram1
  /Subprogram2
  ...
  /Subprogram7
  CMakeLists.txt
```

My CMakeLists.txt :

```
project(Project)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O0 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11" )

include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers" )
include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram1/headers" )
include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram2/headers" )
include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram3/headers" )
....
include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram7/headers" )



set( INSTALL_PATH /usr/local/bin/ )
set( INSTALL_MANPAGES_PATH /usr/local/man/man1 )



add_executable(Subprogram1
         "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/headers.h"
         "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram1/headers/headers1.cpp"
         "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram1/src/main.cpp")

....

add_executable(Subprogram7
         "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/headers.h"
         "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram7/headers/headers7.cpp"
         "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Subprogram7/src/main.cpp")




install( TARGETS Subprogram1 DESTINATION ${INSTALL_PATH} )
...
install( TARGETS Subprogram7 DESTINATION ${INSTALL_PATH} )

install( FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/manpages/Subprogram1.1" DESTINATION ${INSTALL_MANPAGES_PATH})
...
install( FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/manpages/Subprogram7.1" DESTINATION ${INSTALL_MANPAGES_PATH})
```

Well I want to build and install only ONE Subprogram3. In folder /build I typed:

```
cmake ../
make Subprogram3
make install
```

But Cmake and Make util made ALL programs and installed them. I want only one Subprogram3. How to make it? And I want to save my CMakeLists.txt immutable and only find needed commandline parameters to cmake or make utils. How to do it?

Comment: "And I want to save my CMakeLists.txt immutable and only find needed commandline parameters to cmake or make utils." - You cannot. In CMake `make install` always installs everything for which `install` commands are issued in scripts. So you need to adjust your project to be *configurable* in that sence. E.g. by adding an option, which (if set) enables only specific `install()` call.

Comment: Note, if you plan to **pack** your project, then CMake provides [cpack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cpack.1.html) tool. Using this tool you may split your package into the parts according to *COMPONENT* option of the `install` calls. So it is possible to have one part of the package which contains only a specific file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you! If short, answer is no. Because I have not plan to pack my project now. Please write your answer and I will check it if everybody will not get another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installation of CMake project **always** processes **all** `install()` invocations in `CMakeLists.txt`. One cannot ask CMake to install only a *specific* file.

Also, installation phase depends from the `ALL` target as **whole**. CMake doesn't create dependency between installed files (or targets) and commands which creates these files (or targets).

So, if you plan to build and install only a selected file/target, your scripts should issue commands which create only this file/target, and issue `install` only for given file/target. This can be achieved by, e.g., an `option` you passed to `cmake`.

---

Things are quite different, if the project is not installed but **packed** (using [cpack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cpack.1.html)).

Still installation phase is completely performed, and it still depends from `ALL` as whole.

But it is possible to distribute files, `install`-ed in the project, into **several packages**. So one of this packages will contain only a specific file. This is achieved by assigning different *COMPONENT* options for `install` command.

Comment: I'm hoping you can clarify what seems to be two contradictory statements made in this answer:  "One cannot ask CMake to install only a specific file."    and "your scripts should issue commands which create only this file/target, and issue install only for given file/target.  This can be achieved by, e.g., and option you passed to cmake".  Are you referring to cmake command-line options or the option() keyword available inside CMakeLists.txt files?

Comment: @RichvonLehe: I refer to the [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) command. But this command is, among other things, for processing user-specified command-line options. As for possible contradictions, if a script `CMakeLists.txt` issues only a single `install()` call, then upon `make install` only that call will be processed. That is, it is true that CMake processes **all** install calls, but it is also true that only a single file will be installed.